# Detemine the minimum of two random variable

Tags: probability

The temperatures in Chicago and Detroit are $x^0$ and $y^0$, respectively. These temperatures are not assumed to be independent; namely, we are given: 1) $P(x^0=70)$, 2) $P(y^0 =70)$ and $P(max(x^0,y^0)=70)$. Determine $P(min(x^0,y^0)=70)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basic approach.** Rewrite $P(x = 70)$ as

$$
P(x = 70) = P(x = 70, y < 70) + P(x = 70, y = 70) + P(x = 70, y > 70)
$$

(do you see why this is true?) and rewrite $P(y = 70)$ similarly.  In the same way, rewrite $P(\max\{x, y\} = 70)$ as

$$
P(\max\{x, y\} = 70) = P(x = 70, y < 70) + P(x < 70, y = 70) + P(x = 70, y = 70)
$$

(do you see why *this* is true?) and rewrite $P(\min\{x, y\} = 70)$ similarly.

The question then becomes: Express the expansion of $P(\min\{x, y\} = 70)$ as a linear combination of the expansions of $P(x = 70)$, $P(y = 70)$, and $P(\max\{x, y\} = 70)$.  That is, add and subtract copies of those three quantities, in such a way as to obtain $P(\min\{x, y\} = 70)$.

Comment: So is the solution: $P(X=70)+P(Y=70)-P(max{X,Y}=70)$?